# d3 zooming by click ctrl and mousewheel, disable browserzoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, zooming, dagre-d3

i want to zoom a dagre-d3 graph by clicking ctrl and mousewheel. If i dont press ctrl i want that the browser scroll is active. When i want to pan the graph it should work without clicking ctrl. Is it possible? I have made a fiddle but it does not work.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
if(ctrlPressed == true){
inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
});
svg.call(zoom);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobiask/bbxvhx17/61/)

Comment: what is strg? kindly update you question with that information.

Comment: oh sorry. I mean ctrl. Strg is german.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer in stackoverflow.com/a/47421474/1111654

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally get it work.
But the zoom is not like the normal d3 zoom behavior because it does not zoom to the center.

```
see Code in fiddle
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobiask/bbxvhx17/64/)